# Multiple File Splitting in Windows or Linux

Tags: linux, windows, san

We have a 21TB LUN full of images that are approx 600K in size in multiple sub folders on the disk. We are trying to split the 21TB LUN into 8 smaller LUNs that are about 2.6TB a piece in order to process the images more effectively.

My question is how we can determine what 2.6TB is on the drive? What is the best tool to mark this data so we can copy it to the new smaller LUNs with robocopy or emcopy without overfilling the smaller LUNs? Is there a third-party tool that would be better suited for this task? The drive is currently connected to a Windows system, but we can also use Linux to split up the files.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You should provide some information on requirements for handling the sub-folders. Is it OK to split up the contents of a single folder? If not, this becomes a knapsack problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/dsplit/ is the right tool for this job. It is designed for splitting up files into CD or DVD sized groups, but you can specify 2.6TB as a custom target size. It functions by creating directories full of hardlinks to the original files, which take up minimal space but then allow you to simply "copy" the contents of those directories.